# How to set up a sandbox account in Sequelize / Node.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, permissions, sequelize.js, backend

I am trying to set up a sandbox user in Sequelize (that can read from the database, but cannot write / edit it). I already have my user model and relations in place. I can easily add a role enum to the user model to specify one or more "sandbox" accounts.

However, how should I go about setting those permission? Do I have to check every single database post / delete / update route against user permissions or can I use a middleware somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a table to store user wise, access on different database and different permissions (read/write etc).

Create a middleware which authorizes user and this middleware is responsible to authorize user to do action, based on that perform further actions

Comment: Sounds in the direction of what I am looking for... Do you have a more concrete example?

Comment: just search role based authorization on google you may get many examples, one of is here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/28/nodejs-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api